# To Pass an ArrayList without using Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

In my application I've an Splash Activity which is the launcher. In this activity I'm calling some web services and saving the data in an array list. From the Splash Activity it goes to Login page and from there to the Dashboard page.
I would like to know whether it is possible to access the array list which was saved in the Splash Activity during the launch of the application.

Is there anyway doing this, other than passing an intent or making an arraylist static

Comment: You can save the details from arraylist to a file, or database or if it´s not too much, sharedpreferences...

Comment: You could use a Singleton. Or Write your ArrayList to the filesystem (SharedPreferences). Or save it to a sqlite database. There are many possible solutions, depends on your use-case.

Comment: class SplashActivity{public static List mList = new ArrayList();} class LoginActvt{public onCreate(){ SplashActivity.mList }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `ArrayList` in `Singleton` class and access that using `Singleton`

```
public class AppDataManager {
     private static AppDataManager appDataManager;
     private ArrayList<String> arrString;

private AppDataManager() {

    }

    public static AppDataManager getInstance() {
        if (appDataManager == null) {
            synchronized (AppDataManager.class) {
                if (appDataManager == null) {
                    appDataManager = new AppDataManager();
                    return appDataManager;
                } else {
                    return appDataManager;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return appDataManager;
        }
    }

    public void setArray(ArrayList<String> data) {
         if(arrString == null)
             arrString = new ArrayList<String>();
         this.arrString.addAll(data);
    }

    public void getArray() { return this.arrString;}
}
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

Save it in sharedPreferences as a json and parse it back to arrayList when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data from SplashScreenActivity to CustomApplication